# Very Sleepy profiler - Not picking up the PDB file for information about exe functions?

Tags: profiling, verysleepy

I am trying to used Very Sleepy on a windows service .exe on a machine that doesnt have Visual Studios is not installed. I have copied the .exe .map and .pdb file using xcopy. All these files are in the same folder from where the service is executed.

But when I attach with Very sleepy , all the functions related to the .exe do not have any names but only addresses.

What am I missing out?

BR
Niladri Bose

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just as an update I gave up on using very sleepy and am using amd code analyst very successfully

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/

Highly recomend.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your language is C++: Have you enabled "Debug Information" in the compiler settings? This is what the Visual Studio debugger needs to know about the functions, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine have a recent version of the Windows Debugging Tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009 installed? It might have a very old version of dbghelp.dll which might not be able to read your PDBs (assuming they've been generated w/ a recent compiler).

You could also try a more recent version of Very Sleepy - I've got one on my blog at http://hoffesommer.com

Comment: The link is dead. What do you mean by "more recent"? BTW I have a Very Sleepy fork [here](https://github.com/CyberShadow/verysleepy) as well.